# heroku + android : database integration?

Tags: android, heroku

I have a Heroku Rails app and am in the process of developing a mobile companion app.  I would like to use the same databases that I have on Heroku for the app.  What is the best way to go about doing this?  Are there any tutorials for beginners?

I know that Heroku used to have a Parse add-on, but it doesn't seem this exist anymore.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what kind of companion app you want. If you're building an Android one, you should probably add a REST API api to you main API that exposes the data your companion app needs. You could also look into just making your Rails app work really well in mobile browsers and not worry about building an actual native app.

Heroku has several resources that might interest you:

- [Mobile category on Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/mobile)
- [Getting started with iOS and Sinatra](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-ios-development-sinatra-cedar)
- [Helios, Open Source Framework for Mobile](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2013/4/2/helios)

Comment: thanks for your advice.  I'm not clear what a REST API is; do you have any links to tutorials on this?  It seems like the Heroku Mobile links all have to do with iOS, and I'm developing for Android.

Answer (score 0):

I'm learning more about HTTP requests using android and found the following tutorial to be a good place to start:

http://mgmblog.com/2008/10/01/android-ruby-on-rails-app-setup-and-httpclient-hello-world/

Unfortunately, it was written 5 years ago and there are a lot of things that won't work anymore.  So I rewrote the example, which you can try out here:

https://github.com/ttseng/android-rails-example

Hope that's helpful to other beginners.